# IP address in my ISP's netblock resolves to google

Tags: dns

This appears to be the same as in the following question https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97353/google-com-dns-resolved-to-addresses-of-isp?newreg=6f573e129a3f4227a43c4a5b7f580ee2

I have noticed that everytime I start a browser, I was getting a connection to one or more address in my ISP's netblock.

Using Wireshark, these connections showed a TLS setup to Google with Google certificate. Typing the address into my address bar would take me directly to Google search. Any idea what this about?

Comment: As Z.T. commented in the linked question, this is generally done by Google in order to shorten latency of the popular requests. Can you please be more precise what supplementary information you need regarding this question?

Comment: @begueradj  ServerFault would not be appropriate for this question.  SuperUser would be.